# How do I detect a change to the language in a document in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There are a number of events for detecting when a document is focused `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` or when a document's content or metadata is changed (e.g. `workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`), but is there any way to detect when the syntax language of a file has changed?

The property is available under `window.activeTextEditor.document.languageId`, but I can't seem to find a way to detect when this value changes.

Comment: Just a guess: try the document-open event.

Answer (score 0):

The [VSCode API Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) describes the *setLanguageConfiguration* function which indirectly provides the answer:

> Note that calling this function will trigger the *onDidCloseTextDocument* event   followed by the *onDidOpenTextDocument* event.

Registering handlers for these events confirmed that they do indeed fire when the languageId changes.